# Email client to send unmodified HTML emails

Tags: email, email-client

Looking for a (free) email client that will allow me to quickly send HTML emails without modifying the code at all. The company I work for uses a marketing service that allows me to do this, but the process of creating/modifying an email through their site is pretty slow, and it would be really nice to have a quick way to send a test email without having to go through this process.

I have a few clients already that I use to view test emails before sending them out: Outlook Express, Outlook 2007, and Thunderbird. All of these modify my code automatically before sending it (to varying degrees, Thunderbird seems to work best but still significantly alters the code). My research has turned up different ways to send HTML emails with these clients but every method I have tried changes the code.

Ideally, I would like to be able to open a new message, paste the code, and send the test email in as few clicks as possible, without having to do any extra steps to make sure the code isn't modified. Being able to view/modify the code in the client would be nice but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop PipesLab platform which includes a 'Send Mail' block and which should be an accurate solution for you. You can run [example project](https://pipeslab.com/projects/wY2GepeSGyCeoI9g4iwwf0jaCkaFhQbr) with it (after filling required fields)

In the near future there will be more blocks which allow you to do more sophisticated jobs, like sending emails in batch where each message will have auto generated content according to the user profile.

Contact me about any opinions or ideas about it.

Comment: Seems to meet my needs pretty well. The only problem I can see is that it seems to break long lines and insert an "=" at the end, and after every "=" in the code it inserts "3D".

Comment: Example: 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="centered" align="center" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif; text-align: center;"> 

becomes

<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" class=3D"centered" =
align=3D"center" width=3D"100%" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; font-fa=
mily: 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif; text-align: center;">

Comment: This is a [proper behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4016098/2500554). Mail sender need to choose one of encodings from _base_, _quoted-printable_, ... or _8bit_ for _Content-Transfer-Encoding_ header. Mail reader should render properly message irrespective of choosen encoding. I suppose you would like to encode mail with _8bit_ which handles non ASCII chars. But there is a good chance that lines in your html will be more than 998 chars long, so they will not follow RFC2045 rules for 8bit text and message will be encoded differently. PipesLab has now option to force _8bit_ using line split